# help with automatic Rails authlogic login for dummy accounts (grabs username/pw from database to log in)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, spree

I am using rails 2.3.5 with Spree 0.10.2 (which uses authlogic) and i am trying to have an automatic login with a dummy system. For instance, instead of requiring a user to enter a username and password, i want to grab that username and password from a database and log in automatically from the backend.

currently, the code for logging in requires submitting this form tag with the username and password credentials. The password uses a password_field and I'm pretty sure i cant just replace that with a hidden_field.

```
    <% form_tag user_session_path do  %>
  <div id='password-credentials'>
    <p>
      <%= label :user_session, :login, t("email") %><br />
      <%= text_field :user_session, 'login', :class => 'title' %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= label :user_session, :password, t("password") %><br />
      <%= password_field :user_session, 'password', :class => 'title' %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label>
      <%= check_box :user_session, :remember_me %>
      <%= label :user_session, :remember_me, t('remember_me') %>
      </label>
    </p>

  <p><%= submit_tag t("log_in"), :class => 'button primary'%></p>

<% end %>
```

how do i code this so i can submit the correct credentials to authlogic with a global variable @username and @password from the controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're testing the log-in form you should be able to do this:

```
@user = User.find(1) # where this is your dummy user
UserSession.create(@user)
```

Comment: You're right, I can totally get away with just using that instead of actually "logging in" to get the User Session. Thanks